# database design for a market

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to design database for a market with simple and few objects for selling using NodeJS, MongoDB and Mongoose. Because I'm new to MongoDB and NoSQL designs, I need a guide for designing it.
My implementation is here:

```
var orderSchema = new Schema({
    orderId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    orderType: {
        type: String, enum: ['OBJEC1',
            'OBJECT2',
            //other objects
            ], default: 'ALBUM'
    },
    price: { type: String, enum: ['PRICE1', 'PRICE2', 'PRICE3'] },
    coverPhoto: { type: String, default: '' },

    photos: [{
        address: { type: String, default: 'media/uploads' },
    }],

    orderQuantity: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    isChecked: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Besides, I'll save reference of each order to its related user. Am I right, or not? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you designed your schema based on the logic seems good. One thing is you have used default in all the fields.

First, you should understand that default is optional and default is used only when you want to populate some value during the data is created.

Example: you have default for `date` field, here it is good to have. You don't want to manually assign a date during processing the data. So only unless your field should have common default value when creation then you go ahead otherwise remove the default field and make sure the data is inserted properly.

you can use `required` attribute in case some field is mandatory to create a document in the collection. I guess `orderType` a mandatory field so don't miss it ever during insertion so make it as `required: true`.

```
var orderSchema = new Schema({
  orderId: {
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  },
  orderType: {
   type: String, 
   enum: ['OBJEC1','OBJECT2']      
  },
  price: { 
   type: String, 
   enum: ['PRICE1', 'PRICE2', 'PRICE3'] 
  },
  coverPhoto: { 
   type: String 
  },
  photos: [{
    address: { 
       type: String        
    }
  }],
  orderQuantity: { 
   type: Number    
  },
  isChecked: { 
   type: Boolean, 
   default: true 
  },
  date: { 
   type: Date, 
   default: Date.now 
  }
});
```